# Densityplot: isolines

Tags: plotting

I'm plotting a densityplot map from interpolated data.

I need to draw lines in which the value of my function is constant (isolines), but to be constant is not the function itself but a manipulation:
I plot z(x,y)=a(x)-b(x,y) the isoline is b(x,y)=costant

```
plotter[min_, max_, NumberOfTicks_] := 
 DensityPlot[
  If[S*DOS[x] < 1, 
   If[δ - λ > 0, δ - λ, 0.1], -1], {x, 
   0.02, 0.5}, {S, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {2.5, 0}}, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["DeepSeaColors"][
      LogarithmicScaling[#, min, max]] &), 
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[{ColorData["DeepSeaColors"], {0, 2}}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 370, 
    Ticks -> ({LogarithmicScaling[#, min, max]} & /@ (min (max/min)^
          Range[0, 2, 1/NumberOfTicks]))], 
  ClippingStyle -> {RGBColor["NightBlue"]}, Frame -> True, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 12}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "I"}]
plotter[0.1, 3, 2]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Could you please post the definitions of your functions and any other relevant code?

Comment: People here generally like users to post Mathematica code instead of descriptions, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.

Comment: @Iris, actually all we really need are the definitions of `a[x]` and `b[x,y]`, which you've left out.

Comment: But in my opinion, the general question of combining a density plot with an isoline is answered below, and doesn't really depend on the actual definitions of the functions involved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to put a contour plot of `b[x,y]` on top of a density plot of `a[x]-b[x,y]`, easy enough to do

```
a[x_] := Sin[5 x]
b[x_, y_] := Sqrt[2 x^2 + 3 y^2 - 2 x y]
Show[
 DensityPlot[a[x] - b[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}],
 ContourPlot[b[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
  ContourShading -> False]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: @Iris, great!  If you want to include only a single contour line with a given value, use something like `ContourPlot[b[x, y] == 4, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 ContourShading -> False]`

Comment: Great, It works! Thank you
I'm new in using mathematica

Comment: @Iris, glad to help.  If that solves it, be sure to click the check mark next to the answer so it isn't listed as an unanswered question any longer.

Comment: done! I'm new on this site too. I'm really grateful!!

Comment: Well, then, [take the tour!](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: great answer, but could be also combined into one plot with: `DensityPlot[a[x] - b[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, MeshFunctions -> (b[#1, #2] &), Mesh -> 5]`

Comment: @chuy, I did not know that, great!